# Taking data from database in head section of site

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

May be this is a silly question but the structure of the web site is `index.php`, `head.php`, `footer.php`
So I include `head.php` and `footer.php` in index page. All the head stuff are in `head.php`

Now I want to put Facebook share button on the site so I've added in the `head.php`

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="404">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="404">
<meta property="og:locale" content="bg_BG" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of site" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL of the content" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE HERE" />

<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="name" />
```

My question is how to take `<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE HERE" />` since on every page is different image which user can share.

I have code with which I retrieve images from the database but is in index page i.e. below of `<head></head>` part. If I put

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://website.com/image/'.$row['image'].'"/>
```

it doesn't work since at this point there is no `$row['image']` yet.

**UPDATE**

Ok this is what I've done based on @RickJames answer. I've created file **init.php** and I put this in it

```
<?php  
$pdo = Database::connect();
if(isset($_GET['image_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['image_id'])){
    $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];                        

    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT image_name from images WHERE image_id= :image_id ");

    $result->bindParam(':image_id', $image_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($result->execute()) 
    {
        $row_name = $result->fetch();               
    }       
 }
 Database::disconnect();
 ?>
```

In every page where I need this I've made this includes at the top of the page

```
<?php 
     include 'misc/database.inc.php';
     include 'misc/init.php';
     include 'misc/head.php'; 
?>
     // rest of the page
```

The in the head: `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $row_name['image_name']; ?>"/>`

This way I didn't change rest of the page structure. I will follow @Rick's suggestion to move out in this file all the queries but for now will work like this.

@RickJames is this acceptable solution since it is working now? Is there something that I can improve or should I let it like this?

Comment: short answer, move your db query to head.php

Comment: Why is there no $row['image'] yet?

Comment: you have to call the query before fetching image from database

Comment: Because I query database in `index.php`..

Comment: There are 2 approaches here that may work 1:Move your Db and related code before meta is called. 
 2nd: Use Jquery and place value of your desire in the meta tag

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can't use  $row['image']  since it is not querying yet. But I can't move whole part before head of the page.. It will require to rewrite whole site..

Comment: Create function inside index.php and other file with the same name and use that function in `<meta property="og:image" content="" />`. Can this help?

Comment: @KaushaMehta may be will help. Can you provide me with some example? It is basically what Rick suggest, right?

Comment: Ok, i'll comment it out after few mins.

Comment: @noobie-php how this can be done?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **`init.php`** that loads before all other **PHP** pages, i.e. even before **`head.php`**

In this page include all your *database queries* for the page and then use them in the later sections, e.g. **`head.php`**, **`index.php`**, **`footer.php`**, etc., as you need them.
.

**init.php** below:

---

```
<!--- **init.php:**  --->
<?php    //**init.php:**

  $servername = "localhost"; 
  $username = "username"; 
  $password = "password"; 
  $dbname = "myDB";

  // Create connection 
  $conn = new mysqli(
    $servername, 
    $username, 
    $password, 
    $dbname
  ); 

  // Check connection 
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
  } 


  $sql1 = "SELECT image FROM table_name WHERE image_id = " .$_GET["image_id"]
  $result1 = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of first row/image only
    $row1 = $result->fetch_assoc());
  } 
  else { echo "result1 has 0 results"; } 

  $sql2 = "SELECT first_name FROM employees"; 
  $result2 = $conn->query($sql);  //use result2 later in code
                                  //with a loop and $row2
  if ($result2->num_rows <= 0) {
    echo "result2 has 0 results"; 
  } 


  $conn->close();

?>
```

.

**head.php** below:

---

```
<!--- START **head.php:**  --->
<head>
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="404">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="404">
  <meta property="og:locale" content="bg_BG" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Title of site" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="URL of the content" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://website.com/image/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="name" />
</head>
<!--- END **head.php:**  --->
```

.

**index.php** below:

---

```
<!--- START **index.php:**  --->
<HTML>
  include 'init.php';
  include 'head.php';
  <BODY>
  ..... blah, blah, blah
  </BODY>
  include 'footer.php';    
</HTML>
```

Comment: Ok, so if I have in `init.php`: `SELECT * FROM images`. How to call this in `index.php` later? Can you give me some example?

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. I have multiple queries on the page whit different variables and tables..

Comment: Now is a little bit clear but how I will get `$image_var` in the `init.php`

Comment: multiple queries no problem, use $SQL1, $SQL2, etc... with $result1, $result2, etc... and $row1, $row2, etc...

Comment: as for the `$image_var`/`$image_id` how are you getting it now/where is it coming from?  Are you passing it in the URL?  If so, grab it using `$_GET["image_id"]`

Comment: Yes, I passing it via URL and I don't understand how to grab it on both pages - `init.php` and `index.php` at the same time. On the button where I paasing it is `<a href=index.php?image_id=$image_id` and then I take it in index.php to show only this image

Comment: you don't grab it from both pages.  you call `index.php?image_id=1234`, but in your `index.php` you **INCLUDE** both `init.php` and `head.php` in that order

Comment: Thank's. Let me try this and will write what is happen in few minutes.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

Create one function in all the files where you use **header.php**.

**header.php**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo meta_og_image(); ?>"/>
```

**index.php**

```
function meta_og_image() {
    //Write your query here, and get only one field like SELECT image FROM table_name
    return $row['image'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it now and will let you know what is happen.

Comment: Where should be this function... at the top of the page? Because if it must be at the top again - can't do it because I get `image_id` var from another page in order to view just this image.

Comment: @John Yes, it is before header.php and after connection include.

Comment: So I don't see how will be done then since on the page `index.php` part I have `if(isset($_GET['image_id'])){ $image_id = $_GET['image_id']; ...` then query and show only this image. At the beginning of the page I don't have yet this variable.

Comment: @John Can you give me the whole code you are trying to? You can create chat session too if you want. Then i can help you.

Comment: It is as I wrote on the `index.php` I have `Include 'head.php' if(isset($_GET['image_id'])){ $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];  // showing image } include 'footer.php'` That's it.

Comment: @John take a look at my example

Comment: @John `$image_id` means what you want to display in `<meta property="og:image" />`, right?

Comment: Yes, and also by image_id I query the table `select * images where image_id=$image_id` and showing that image with other values from DB as name, post date etc..

Comment: @John Ok, Do like this, `function meta_og_image() {
    //Write your query here, and get only one field like select image images where image_id=$image_id
    return $row['image'];
}`

Comment: You don't understand me or I don't understand it. There is no `$_GET['image_id']`  before the `include 'head.php'` So I can't use it in that query in function before that.

Comment: @John then you have only one way that you have to add new query in header.php where you want image. Because if you use jQuery then the value is not coming inside view sourse so may be that is not useful. So you have only one way query for one field in header.php.

Comment: So my only option is @RickJames solution.

Comment: Yes, but you can write query directly to header, dont need to create new file for just one query.

Comment: @John no you don't have to create a new file for just one query, but you said you had **more than** one query... so, that's why I suggested putting them all in one init.php or queries.php file... whatever you want to call it.  If you think my answer is the solution, please "check it", marking it as the solution - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but will work with Jquery. I havent tested it but i think it should be ok.

Use it in your `index.php` pref at the end of the page or use proper semantics i.e `isset()` etc

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("meta[property='og\\:image']").attr("content", <?php echo $row['image'];?>);// Note you can place any variable at the place of $row['image'] and it will be applied to the image

        });
```

Comment: It is get image name in the `jQuery` but it didn't place it in the head part. This is how I tried in the head but where is $row['image'] is empty:`<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo 'http://example.com/upload/'.$row['image']; ?>" />`

Comment: Also is I see here `jQuery("meta[property='og\\:image']").attr("content", <?php echo $row['image'];?>);` that `$row['image']` echoing random image every time

Comment: Well it cant be a random image, it will always be the last value from `$row['image']` and to avoid any issues i recommended that you add this code at the end of the page.

Comment: It is random. Do i need to write anything in `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo 'http://example.com/upload/'.$row['image']; ?>" />` or just leave it blank?

Comment: It cannot be random if you are talking about my code, but if you wanna see it is random or not try `echo $row['image'];` on every page load, also i tried the code on fiddle and it works absolutely fine, so the only issue left behind is your logic by which you get value inside  `$row['image'];`

Comment: On every page refresh image on the page is the same but when I look in page source on every refresh image here `jQuery("meta[property='og\\:image']").attr("content", <?php echo $row['image'];?>);` i.e. $row['image'] is different.

Comment: @John: let me share fiddle with you, it cannot change logically. https://jsfiddle.net/5rh6fn7h/1/ , i would still suggest you look for your logic

Comment: But why on the page only this get random image every time.. all other images on the page are not random

Comment: Ok, i found what was the problem with the random image. Now is the right image BUT on facebook scraper tell me that `og:image was not defined`